# How to add to a table cell without overriding the data?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am building a GUI grading system in C# that implements SQL Server 2012. When the program begins there are tabs that control different aspects of the program such as adding, updating, or deleting records; viewing a grade GridView for all or single student; and then viewing all student records. Right now I have all of a student's grades in 1 cell in a table called StudentGrades, it looks like this:

```
Student ID     Student Grades
00001          100, 58, 72, 10, 25, 50, 93, 74, 30
00002          10, 40
00003          88, 60, 20, 45
```

As you can see not every student has the same amount of grades, so I thought it would be easier to have all the grades occupy 1 cell rather than have a table with empty cells.

What I am trying to accomplish is when the user updates a student record and adds a new grade, I want the program to query the database and SELECT the StudentGrades from the StudentGrades table and then return the value. Once it is returned, I want to add the new grade to the result and then update the database with a new script. Kind of like this:

```
string select = "select StudentGrades from StudentGrades where Student_ID = inputStudentID";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(select, conn);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
string temp = reader;
temp += "," + newStudentGrade;
//Script to update table here
```

Is this possible in Sql Server 2012 and C#? What value would reader hold after querying the table?

Comment: It would be easier if you normalize your data.

Comment: @wewesthemenace, I'm not sure how that would make this easier. I already have primary and foreign keys set up and split my data into differing tables for easier access to certain data.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your db directly (if that's no problem) like this:

```
UPDATE StudentGrades
SET [Student Grades] = [Student Grades] + @newgrade  --do concatenation
WHERE Student_ID = @inputStudentID
```

And, passing parameter `@newgrade` with `"," + newStudentGrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a really bad idea. You should have another table called StudentGrade with a StudentID foreign key, and have one row per grade in that so you can insert/update/delete them normally. Then adding a grade will be as simple as `INSERT INTO StudentGrade(StudentID, Grade) VALUES(x, y)`.

Database columns should be atomic - there should only be one piece of data in each field. Ignoring this rule leads to pain and suffering. That you're spending time trying to write an update script instead of a simple `INSERT` is the first symptom of this; it will get worse from here.